# MSYS2 cant find MPI

Tags: windows, mpi, msys2

I download Msys2 in Windows, and MPI from [mircrosoft MPI](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=100593), and add it to environment path.

However when I check`which mpi` , it says `which : no mpi in ...` . I think the environment path in Msys2 is different from the one in my computer, but I dont know how to add it to Msys2's path.

Then I check `pacman -Ss mpi` , Msys2 just gives packages for gcc and dtc(I already download them in Msys2).

Thanks for your help！

Comment: Either modify PATH manually using `export PATH=...:$PATH`, or open MSYS2 shell using `C:\msys64\msys2_shell.cmd -ucrt64 -full-path` (replace `ucrt64` with your preferred environment). Also note that there's a package called [`...-msmpi`](https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-msmpi?repo=ucrt64), which doesn't have `mpi.exe`, but has some other executables named `mpi??.exe`. I'm not familiar with MPI, so not sure if it's useful or not.